# Rails 4 custom translations per User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

We have an CMS application which allows to create shops from a backend for multiple users.. now when we want to implement translations we face a problem. Translations are just stored with a locale but what we need would be a user.id and a locale. Because each user can have his own translations per language.

I tried to implement a i18n Backend as described in this railscast but am now stucking with 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends?view=asciicast
the customization per user.

is there a way to add an additional column into the translations and ask for local and user_id?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single best solution for your given problem. It depends on your application. Given the information I have I'd suggest something like:

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  before_filter :set_locale

  private
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = current_user.language || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

This would set the `18n.locale` to the language settings of your `current_user`. Obviously you need a `language` attribute in your `users` model for this to work.

Please have a look at http://xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/i18n.html for more examples.